# How to retrieve IP address of JMX Notification message?

Tags: jmx

I am deploying two Java application with JMX server. The two sending message to JMX Client. However I can't differentiate where the message come from.

How to retrieve IP address of JMX Notification message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in way to determine this,  but here's a couple of suggestions :

On the notification sender side, add an app id to the notifications user-data or the source so the listener can distinguish between senders.

On the listener side,  you could specify the same identifier as the handback object when you register the listener. That way you will know which source the notification came from.

Comment: I just feel this way is very hacky. However it seems this is the only way.